# load dynamic data with ajax and hidden divs

Tags: ajax, jquery, html

I want to create something similar to collapsible divs to show or hide content to the user.
I don't want the content to be load in one ajax call because the data is huge.
Each time a user click on an option, an ajax call will load the data.

I started using append to create the divs. Since I don't know how much option there is on each one, I couldn't build the divs in advance.

**The problem** I'm having with **appends** is when a user click on option B, options b1,b2,b3 are loading and the divs are created. But when the user decide to go back to option A and then back to option B, the divs are created again and now they are multiple.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Show the piece of code..

Comment: you can check if the elements already exist before appending and only appends if it dosen't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I sayed in my comment you can do something like this:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/V4dXC/4/)

```
<div id="option-a">option A</div>
<div id="option-b">option B</div>
<div id="option-c">option C</div>
<div id="option-d">option D</div>


$("#option-b").on("click",  function(){
    //if element doesn't exist
    if( $('#submenu-b').length <= 0 ){
        //add elemnent
        $("#option-b").append("<span id='submenu-b'><div>B1</div><div>B2</div><div>B3</div></div>");    
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't know how many options are available. This will be load dynamiclly fron json. So i can't use on option b click because maybe there isnt option b.